# Cassandra java ORM

Tags: java, orm, cassandra

Does anyone know a something similar to spring-data-mongo but for Cassandra ?

spring cassandra is alpha.
easy cassandra is not so good.
after working with spring-data-mongo, it is very hard to think in CQL way.

thanks, and sorry for being lame.

Comment: Try to use Hector: http://1and1.github.io/hector/build/html/index.html

Comment: yes,i have looked, but this is not an orm, it is a database client. 
i am looking just for a easy way to persist complex java objects without diving deep into cassandra table structures and joins

Comment: The problem with that approach is that unless you're aware of Cassandra schema, you will not be able to leverage its architecture to run performant queries.  In fact, CQL does not support many query types, because they can't be executed fast, making a general purpose ORM a difficult proposition.

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look into Kundera (https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera), it is a very good Java option for Cassandra (and other datastores). It it JPA compliant, has an amazing development team (very responsive and fast moving) and excellent documentation.

HTH

Answer (score 2):

Try Easy Cassandra https://github.com/otaviojava/Easy-Cassandra. It works good for me

Answer (score 0):

Try [abacus-common](https://cdn.rawgit.com/landawn/AbacusUtil/master/docs/CassandraExecutor_view.html)

CQL is supported with Entity/Map parameters. Here is a simple CRUD sample:

```
    @Test
    public void test_crud() {
        Account account = createAccount();
        // create
        String sql_insert = NE.insert(ID, GUI, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, LAST_UPDATE_TIME, CREATE_TIME).into(Account.class).sql();
        cassandraExecutor.execute(sql_insert, account);

        // read
        String sql_selectByGUI = NE.select(ID, GUI, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME).from(Account._).where(L.eq(ID, L.QME)).sql();
        Account dbAccount = cassandraExecutor.queryForEntity(Account.class, sql_selectByGUI, account);

        // update
        String sql_updateByLastName = NE.update(Account.class).set(FIRST_NAME).where(L.eq(ID, L.QME)).sql();
        dbAccount.setFirstName("newFirstName");
        cassandraExecutor.execute(sql_updateByLastName, dbAccount);

        // delete
        String sql_deleteByFirstName = NE.deleteFrom(Account.class).where(L.eq(ID, L.QME)).sql();
        cassandraExecutor.execute(sql_deleteByFirstName, dbAccount);

        // check
        assertFalse(cassandraExecutor.exists(sql_selectByGUI, dbAccount));
    }
```

Declaration: I'm the developer of abacus-common

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Charybdis](https://github.com/omarkad2/charybdis).

It's easy to use and comprehensive.
It supports main Cassandra/Datastax features (LWT, batch queries, async execution...), with intuitive modeling and querying.

Example of an insert query:

- Using DSL API:

  ```
  cqlTemplate.dsl().insertInto(User_Table.user, User_Table.id, User_Table.joiningDate, User_Table.addresses)
             .values(UUID.randomUUID(), Instant.now(), addresses)
             .ifNotExists()
             .execute();
  ```
- Using Crud API:

  ```
  cqlTemplate.crud().create(User_Table.user, new User(...));
  ```

You can have a look at this Chat application (demo with spring boot)
[Charybdis Demo](https://github.com/omarkad2/charybdis-demo) that uses the framework.

btw I am the developer and maintainer of this project.